# Does the integral $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(x+y)^{2020}} \,dx\,dy$ converge or diverge?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> Does the integral
> $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(x+y)^{2020}} \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
> $$
> converge or diverge?

I tried to use linear transformation (replacing $x+y$ with $u$ and $y$ with $v$) and wanted to use the Gaussian integral but did not succeed.

Comment: Could you go into more detail of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

First,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^{2020}}\;dx 
= \frac{1}{1010}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2020}\right) \approx 0.9994
$$
converges (and is, of course, positive).  Then, for any $y$ we have
by translation-invariance
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-(x+y)^{2020}}\;dx 
= \frac{1}{1010}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2020}\right) > 0
$$
which is constant in $y$.  So
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-(x+y)^{2020}}\;dx\;dy = +\infty
$$
The integrand $e^{-(x+y)^{2020}}$ is nonnegative and measurable on $\mathbb R^2$, so Tonelli's theorem is applicable.

Comment: Could you please explain the first step? (the first use of Gamma function)

Comment: change variables $y=x^N$ in $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^N}\;dx = \frac{1}{N}\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^{(1/N)-1}\;dy = \frac{1}{N}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)$$